# How to hide() and show() function for jsp using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

My code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AddNew() 
{
    var partyname = $("#account_id_widget").val();
    var pgroup="NA";
    if(display=="none")
    {
        $("#log").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#addnew').hide();
    }
}
</script>
```

I call this `div`:

```
<div id="log" style="display:none;">
    <%@ include file="recievable_details.jsp" %>
</div>
```

They're JSP which I show on my page and I call function there:

```
<sj:a id="show" button="true" onclick="AddNew()" indicator="true">AddNew</sj:a>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AddNew() 
{
    var partyname = $("#account_id_widget").val();
    var pgroup="NA";
    $('#log').toggle();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do this

```
<script>
function AddNew() 
{
$("#log").toggle();
}
</script>
```

Make Sure you have included jquery in your code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(if you have jquery.min.js file inside the "js" folder  )

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are `missing a variable declaration for display`.

`var display=$('#log').css('display');`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AddNew() 
{
    var partyname = $("#account_id_widget").val();
    var pgroup="NA";
    var display=$('#log').css('display');
    if(display=="none")
    {
        $("#log").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#addnew').hide();
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For hide or show any element u can use Jquery/Javascript

```
<div id="log" style="display:none;">
    <%@ include file="recievable_details.jsp" %>
</div>

<div id="addNew" style="display:none;">
    <%@ include file="recievable_details.jsp" %>
</div>

$("#log").hide(); or $("#log").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving you a javascript function which will help you.

toggles visibility

```
function showhide(id){
    if(document.getElementById(id).className == "showhidediv_show"){
        document.getElementById(id).className="showhidediv_hide";
    }else{
        document.getElementById(id).className="showhidediv_show";
    }
}
```

---

Individual showhide functions

```
function show(id)
{
document.getElementById(id).className="showhidediv_show";   
}
function hide(id)
{
    document.getElementById(id).className="showhidediv_hide";
}
```